# Remove the vertices of polylines which are too close to eachother

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I want to remove the vertices or nodes of a polyline which are too close to each other. In other words, if the polylines are too close to each other, I want to cut both of them in the place where they are close to eachother ( see image).[image]

I tryed v.clean from GRASS (break) but apparently it does not work for such a case.

**First attempt**

I tryed the the first recommanded methode (see below). but it does not work ar I wish. Hier I attach a new figure to show the details of the chosen parameter for v.clean.

[image]

Comment: Are the vertices to remove always the end or start vertices? What if the next vertex is very far from the removed vertex, would you be happy with a one kilometer long gap? You should perhaps make a new sketch and mark clearly what vertices should be removed, or a before-after image pair.

Answer (score 6):

In grass window you can click on the advanced parameters drop down menu and select *v.in.ogr* snap tolerance to select the distance under which your points will be removed.

Using the break option in v.clean as you did should do the work.

[image: v.clean example picture]

Comment: I can't find the v.in.ogr in the GRASS plugin. I updated GRASS, no clue.

Comment: it's not a plug-in, it's in the _v.clean_ options, just above the output line. I will edit my answer with a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the nodes from the poly-line file then buffer the nodes by the threshold distance. In your example, it looks like the threshold is one meter. Then you would use the difference tool with the line layer set as the "Input Layer" and the buffers set as the "Difference Layer". The output would be a line/poly-line layer where no line is within a certain distance from any other line.